# In need of a continuous testing package

Tags: package

I'm looking for an emacs package that can continuously run my unit tests. As I make changes, I'd like to be alerted as soon as a test fails. Preferably, a package that is language agnostic would be great (this is a C++ project). In my case, running the tests is all command-line driven.

Does such a package exist?

Comment: Why do you want to run it in Emacs? (As opposed to running Jenkins / Travis etc and using some notification mechanism).

Comment: I'll update my question with more explanation. I'd like to have a buffer with the results so I don't have to leave emacs. Also, hooking into when emacs saves a file to trigger a rebuild is useful.

Comment: I'm asking because Jenkins has tolerable interface, if you want to use it from `eww`. At least for browsing, it's OK. You could probably set SCM in Jenkins to look for changes in a directory so it would start up after you build and then just refresh the `eww` buffer to see the results (well, in a few minutes).

Answer (score 5):

You can with the package [auto-recompile](https://github.com/tuhdo/auto-recompile). I took it from [here](http://fredrik.hubbe.net/hacks/auto-recompile.html) and fixed a bug to make it compatible with latest Emacs. To use it:

- First load the package in your Emacs (I assume you know how to do this).
- Then, `M-x auto-recompile`. After that, it displays a message `Auto-recompile mode is on`.
- Next, `M-x compile` and run your test command.
- Now, everytime you save, the compile command (which is the test command you've just executed) runs automatically and display in `*compilation*` buffer.

You should bind a key to `auto-recompile` to toggle it on/off when needed, since it's annoying when enabled globally because the recompile is triggered in unrelated modes.

You can combine it with `auto-save-mode` to achieve what you want: periodically see test results by periodically save your current buffer and in turn, invoke `auto-recompile` (the function is taken from [here](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoSave#toc7)):

```
(defun save-buffer-if-visiting-file (&optional args)
  "Save the current buffer only if it is visiting a file"
  (interactive)
  (if (and (buffer-file-name) (buffer-modified-p))
      (save-buffer args)))

(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'auto-save-mode)
(add-hook 'auto-save-hook 'save-buffer-if-visiting-file)
(setq auto-save-timeout 10)             ; auto save every 10 seconds
(setq auto-save-interval 100)           ; auto save every 100 input events
```

Answer (score 2):

I happen to have written [a generic package for doing things on save](https://github.com/wasamasa/firestarter), such as running (shell) commands not too long ago.

It supports shell commands, interactive commands and generic Emacs Lisp code.  When using shell commands, you get a reporting buffer containing output of the entire history and can configure on which condition it should pop up (like for example, only when the command failed with a non-zero status code). Finally, it supports format codes in the commands which are tremendously useful for calls that need to know the current file it's running upon or parts of it. Since it uses a customizable buffer-local variable to determine how to do its job, you can customize it globally, per mode, per directory, per file or even just interactively, unlike things like `M-x compile` where you start with a default and need to change it for every "project" for each new Emacs session.

I believe it to be the simplest solution for a workflow approximating full CI solutions.  If there's anything obvious missing from it, feel free to open an issue on its bug tracker.